# (си) Почему не выполняется присваивание в цикле, а если есть другой цикл то выполнется

Tags: c, числовые-последовательности

Простое присвоение значений элементам массива arr в цикле while не выполняется, хотя сам цикл работает (перебор по i корректный). ПРИЧЕМ если переписать цикл через for и добавить код ДО цикла while (закоменчен) - присваивание корректное. Что за бред? )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int *arr = NULL; 
   int arrSize = 4;
   int i = 0;
   
   arr = (int*)realloc(arr, arrSize*sizeof(int));
   
   /*
   for(i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i){
       arr[i] = i;
       printf("for loop i = %d arr[i] = %d \n",i, arr[i]);
   }    
   i = 0;
   */
   
   while(i < arrSize){
       arr[i] = i;
       ++i;
       printf("while loop i = %d arr[i] = %d \n",i, arr[i]);
       }
       
   return 0;
}
```

[image: Вывод полный / вывод с закоментированным куском]

Answer (score 1):

Только три строки...

```
arr[i] = i;  
++i;
printf("while loop i = %d arr[i] = %d \n",i, arr[i]);
```

Т.е. присваиваете вы `i`-ое значение, увеличиваете `i` и выводите по сути `i+1`-ое значение (следующее, еще не присвоенное)...

Понятно, что в цикле `for` вы присваиваете верные значения, а потом в `while` их читаете, вот и вся "магия"...

Честное слово, ну стыдно же даже на такие простые вопросы отвечать...